# SoundManager 2: How to play a sample using the 360 Player?

Tags: soundmanager2

I am using the 360 player demo and I am trying to only play a portion of the sound file.  Looking at the documentation there is a from and to that you can add to the play function like below:

```
spliceDemo.play({
// start position
from: 500,
// end position
to: 1200,
onstop: function() {
  soundManager._writeDebug('sound stopped at position ' + this.position);
}
});
```

The demo code for the 360 player doesn't seem to have a play function exactly like this one, and adding to and from lines causes an error. The play function in the demo is:

```
play: function() {
  pl.removeClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data.className);
  this._360data.className = pl.css.sPlaying;
  pl.addClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data.className);
  self.fanOut(this);
}
```